# Update MySQl Linked server from sql server trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, linked-server

Error I get when I run

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "WEBSTAGING" returned
>   message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Optional feature not supported".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure
>   trg_DeliveryPartMap_Mysql_Stockupdate, Line 32 The operation could not
>   be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
>   "WEBSTAGING" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

moreover select Query works fine in sql server trigger.

But when I run on Linnked server it works fine

```
UPDATE OpenQuery(WEBSTAGING, 'SELECT inventory, id, originalId  FROM product
WHERE originalId=Xxx') SET inventory = 13
```

Comment: I solved it by calling a stored procedure on Linked Server (MySQL server)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling stored procedure from local server of Linked Server (MySQL Server)

without using OpenQuery I used Exec (Linked server stored procedure)

and it worked

Thanks